# Remove Import Button in odoo tree view

Tags: javascript, xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

I need to remove import button from my tree view and need to add edit button for tree view . How can I do that.. 
Also I need to create button near create button in kanban view to go for another tree view. How can I do that... Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Its simple.. 
we can make create='false' and edit='false' in tree view XML

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the ListView (list_view.js) and change the method `render_buttons`. You can then render a custom template (you can use `ListView.buttons` template as a reference) with the buttons you need.

You can do the same for the KanbanView (kanban_view.js).

Comment: Can you explain this with more details